# Detecting Bus Presence

Tags: level-shifting, 5v, 3.3v, teensy

I have a PCB that connects to an existing device through a simple parallel bus. I want a way to determine whether this device is connected or not.

- The data lines aren't of any help, as they are attached to a 74LVCH245A with a bus hold feature.
- GND is connected to the micro-controllers (Teensy 4.0) ground, so it will always be 0V.
- But 5V power from the bus will be floating (0V with 50k pull-down) when there's no device. It's incompatible with the micro-controller which runs at 3.3V, but I'd imagine there's some small circuit I could build here to connect it to the micro-controllers GPIO.

Given this, what's the best way to connect the 5V power line to a 3.3V GPIO. It seems there's quite a few ways to go about it (e.g. series resistors / diodes, divider, BJT/MOSFET, ICs, etc.). I found [this source](https://next-hack.com/index.php/2017/09/15/how-to-interface-a-5v-output-to-a-3-3v-input/) which seems decent. What would you recommend?

[image]

EDIT: The micro-controller was recently changed, so the schematic's a bit of a mess on that side.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Do you have a schematics or diagram?

Comment: A voltage divider would be a trivial answer. I'm not sure why you'd bother with anything else, really.

Comment: Any reason you don't use a pair of resistors?  That is the typical solution.

Comment: @user1850479 No particular reason. I'm just new to circuit design, so I wasn't sure what was best. Since speed doesn't matter, I'd just need decent values for low current. Would values of ~50k & ~100k work well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cheapest and simplest solution to determine if 5V is present or not is a simple voltage divider with two resistors.

It is definitely not the best as you don't define what best means to you. As you already saw in your links, there's dozens of ways doing it, each best for the purpose, depending on what kind of signal you need to convert.

So just divide the 5V down to 3.3V for an IO pin.

If in doubt, use an analog input pin which can actually measure what the voltage is, in order to require at least 4.5V to be sure something is connected.

The resistor divider impedance can be 10k or lower so it will properly load down the 5V to 0V when it is removed, and the output impedance will be low enough for the analog input.